# Emacs: magit status failed on ssh remote server repo

Tags: emacs, tramp, magit, spacemacs, trampolines

I'm using ssh to connect to a remote server. On the server there is a git repo called `MRFLSSVM`. However, when I execute `magit-status` on:

```
/ssh:qmServer:/home/Chang/qmCodeLab/MRFLSSVM/
```

Magit asks me to `Create repository in /ssh:qmServer:/home/Chang/qmCodeLab/MRFLSSVM/?`.

Any idea how to let magit recognize that repo? (I've already installed git 2.10.0 on /usr/local/git and configured my system (CentOS) to use it by update-alternatives)

-----------Edit------------------------------

```
Error (magit): Magit requires Git >= 1.9.4, you are using 1.8.3.

If this comes as a surprise to you, because you do actually have
a newer version installed, then that probably means that the
older version happens to appear earlier on the `$PATH'.  If you
always start Emacs from a shell, then that can be fixed in the
shell's init file.  If you start Emacs by clicking on an icon,
or using some sort of application launcher, then you probably
have to adjust the environment as seen by graphical interface.
For X11 something like ~/.xinitrc should work.

If you use Tramp to work inside remote Git repositories, then you
have to make sure a suitable Git is used on the remote machines
too.

Error (magit): Magit requires Git >= 1.9.4, but on /ssh:qmServer: the version is 1.8.3.

If multiple Git versions are installed on the host then the
problem might be that TRAMP uses the wrong executable.

First check the value of `magit-git-executable'.  Its value is
used when running git locally as well as when running it on a
remote host.  The default value is "git", except on Windows
where an absolute path is used for performance reasons.

If the value already is just "git" but TRAMP never-the-less
doesn't use the correct executable, then consult the info node
`(tramp)Remote programs'.
```

This problem seems to be `tramp` is not using the correct git on remote server. I've tried to change `magit-git-executable` to `usr/local/git/bin/git` which is the path both of my local and remotes installed git. But this still doesn't work.

Any ideas to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions on this site and Emacs Stack Exchange at the same time.

Comment: FWIW, I don't use magit so I'm guessing at some things here.  Is `magit-git-executable` absolute or relative (is there a leading `/` or not)?  It should probably be absolute if you're explicitly setting it.  Also, try `(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)`.  `C-h v tramp-remote-path` for details.